# Find history of deleted rows from Big Query table

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Is there a way to see deleted rows in Big Query, at least until one month ago? My workplace right now doesn't really care about database administrations so everyone on my team can alter (update, delete, etc) the table contents. I want to know what data has been deleted from the table, as I need it for internal tasks. My goal would be to get every deleted rows from one month ago, or at least get every `DELETE` operations done from the table.

For additional information: I know about snapshot feature, and that's not what I want because then I have to manually restore the table each day, say, from 2023/04/01 to 2023/05/01, and check which row is gone/deleted each day. Or maybe it's the only way?

Comment: You can use the timetravel feature to see the table a 7 days ago. The admin can also extend this time. Take a farm_fingerprint of the some columns and do this query twice (one time for the current and one time for time traveled ). Then compare these tempory tables.